# How can I fix the Run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba

How can I fix the

> Run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument

I have a this line in my code: `Betac = ((t - t0) / (Betah(h, RH, alfa3) + (t - t0))) ^ 0.3`.
It runs correctly when I enter the `h` parameter by myself, but when I input it by variable VBA shows this error.
please help!

```vb
' ????? if I input h here runs correctly
' but when input it in the function argument vba gives run time error '5'

h = 777

RH = Cells(26, 11)
Betafcm = (16.8 / Sqr(fcm))
Betat0 = 1 / (0.1 + t0 ^ 0.2)
alfa1 = (35 / fcm) ^ 0.7
alfa2 = (35 / fcm) ^ 0.2
alfa3 = (35 / fcm) ^ 0.5
Betac = ((t - t0) / (Betah(h, RH, alfa3) + (t - t0))) ^ 0.3
```

Comment: What is `Betah` and how is `h` declared?

Comment: they're both as double

Comment: Betah is a function

Public Function Betah(h, RH, alfa3) As Double

     Betah = 1.5 * h * (1 + (1.2 * RH / 100) ^ 18) + 250 * alfa3
          If Betah > 1500 * alfa3 Then
              Betah = 1500 * alfa3
          End If
    
End Function

Comment: So `Betah` is `Betah(ByRef h As Variant, ByRef RH As Variant, ByRef alfa3 As Variant)`. Make it `Betah(ByVal h As Double, ByVal RH As Double, ByVal alfa3 As Double)`.